# How to get deserialized JTS Geometry field in Grails 4?

Tags: grails, geometry, jts, grails-4

I'm building a small Geo server using PostgreSQL + PostGIS + Grails 4 + Geoserver + React + JTS. The domain class has a `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point` field that is maped to a `sqlType: 'geometry(Point,4326)'`. When I search any `findBy...(...)` search, I cannot get the result, as it is not posible `deserialize`

in Grails 2.x I did not get this problem. It's my first time programming in Grails in 3 years.

```
package ....

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point

class Aqop {
  String  pid
  String  pname
  Float   x
  Float   y
  String  srid
  Point   center

  static mapping = {
    table         'aqop'
    version       false
    autoTimestamp false
    cache         true

    id     column: 'aqop_id'
    pname  column: 'pname',  type: 'text', index: 'aqop_pname_idx'
    pid    column: 'pid',    type: 'text', index: 'aqop_pid_idx'
    x      column: 'x'
    y      column: 'y'
    srid   column: 'srid',   type: 'text'
    center column: 'center', sqlType: 'geometry(Point,4326)'
  }

  static constraints = {
    pname size: 1..128, unique: true
    pid   size: 1..64,  unique: true
    x     nullable: false
    y     nullable: false
    srid  nullable: false, size: 1..64
  }
}
```

This the error message:

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3018)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1752)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1678)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1567)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1972)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:370)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResultViaListCall(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:807)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResult(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:794)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.invokeQuery(AbstractFindByFinder.java:35)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder$1.doInSession(AbstractFindByFinder.java:29)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:42)
....
```

How camn I get deserialized the Domain Object ? Any help is welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: to work around this problem, after the table has been created, I get rid of the `Point   center`field in Grails code, while I keep the table in PostgreSQL / PostGIS. To get the `Geometry` field I call a PostgreSQL / PostGIS store procedure that executes `ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x, y), srid)`

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/snapshot/guide/upgrading.html) Grails 4 is compatible with latest version of Hibernate 5.4. 
Karel Maesen in linked issue comments that latest versions of Hibernate expect latest versions of JTS. 
 Migrate your dependency from `vividsolutions.jts` to `locationtech.jts` and define `Point` as `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point` More info: https://github.com/locationtech/jts