# Hibernate 5.4 PostgisDialect deprecated?

Tags: hibernate, grails-3.0, hibernate-spatial, grails-4

Due to Grails 3 migration to Grails 4 had to upgrade Hibernate 5.1.5 to the latest Hibernate 5.4.14 (including hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-spatial, hibernate-ehcache, hibernate-core...).
JVM: OpenJDK 11 
org.springframework.boot 2.1.12.RELEASE 
Database: PostgreSQL 10.4 installed extension Postgis 2.4. 
According to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-configuration-dialect) hibernate dialect should be associated to

```
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

application.yml:

```
environments:
  development:
    dataSource:
      driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
      dbCreate: update
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
      dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TEST
```

however at Hibernate 5.4.14 the class is empty and noted as deprecated.

Other latest [document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/postgis/package-summary.html) states to implement one of `PostgisPGNNDialect` classes which referes to older postgis version (1.3 and below). 
What hibernate spatial dialect could be implemented instead to be able to map `Geometry` field of the entity class successfully? 
When the `Geometry` field is commented out, no error appears, otherwise appears:

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

Exacly the same error under following link: [How to get deserialized JTS Geometry field in Grails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384610/how-to-get-deserialized-jts-geometry-field-in-grails-4)

***EDIT[20.04.2020]*** Complete stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:125)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:136)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:303)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:305)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:241)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:120)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.list(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:78)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.list(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:77)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.list(GormEntity.groovy:682)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at nbg.LmController.$tt__map(LmController.groovy:53)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
... 48 common frames omitted 
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3068)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1866)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1794)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1767)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1615)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.list(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:96)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.HibernateHqlQuery.executeQuery(HibernateHqlQuery.java:47)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.doList(Query.java:589)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.list(Query.java:568)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi$_list_closure1.doCall(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:120)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:297)
... 63 common frames omitted Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30313036
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:877)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
... 100 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I suggest you use the `PostgisPG95Dialect`. It should work fine with you're postgres/postgis combination.

Comment: Thx for helping! I have tried all available (`PostgisPG95Dialect`, `PostgisPG94Dialect` ...) but no success. Additionally I have created `PostgisDialect` within own package by copying code from version 5.1.5 (which worked before) no success

Comment: I think your problem is elsewhere. Can you verify in the logs that the correct dialect is picked up by you're application? Could you provide the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I have added stacktrace above and checked dialect on runtime using `@Autowired`  `org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore`. It prints outs `PostgisPG95Dialect` as suggested

Comment: `vividsolutions.jts` has been applied for `Geometry` definition and as mentioned, app is running perfectly fine without having geometry property

Comment: I did a test with the Grails 3 version of application (state before migration to Grails 4 ) and Hibernate 5.2.1 (hibernate-spatial, entity-manager..) using `PostgisPG95Dialect` (cause starting from 5.2.*  `PostgisDialect` is deprecated), database connection is the same. Appears completely the same error...

Comment: Seeing the stacktrace, I think the Hibernate type system fails to identify the Geometry field as something to be handled by Hibernate-Spatial. Now, current versions of Hibernate expect newer versions of JTS: See https://github.com/locationtech/jts. The `com.vividsolutions.geom` package has been renamed to `org.locationtech.jts`. Maybe try updating this dependency?

Comment: Yes with `org.locationtech.jts` Geometry field is well initialized i.e issue is being solved! Now it's left to migrate `vividsolutions` to `locationtech` in the entire App, but that's just work.

Comment: Glad it worked! migration is pretty straightforward, basically a rename of the package. For completeness I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the use of the old, deprecated versio for JTS which use the `com.vividsolutions` package names.

Recent versions of Hibernate no longer recognize `com.vividsolutions.geom.Geometry` as a geometry type so fails to engage to proper (de)serialization functions.

The solution is to [upgrade to JTS versions > 1.15](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)